# Editing a large chunk of incorrect assumptions out of a question

Tags: discussion, editing

A recent question about tire sizing prompted me to hunt up [this previous question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17273/how-do-i-determine-my-wheel-size) about tire sizings thinking it might be a duplicate. Putting aside the matter of whether or not it's a duplicate...

I noticed that after accepting the answer, the OP had edited in some incorrect conclusions and extraneous information into his question. I have edited the answer to reflect that those conclusions are incorrect, but given that all he's done is make the whole page longer and more confusing, I was wondering if it would be better to just edit out his incorrect conclusions.

I am well and truly split on whether to leave it as it stands or roll back all the edits. Thoughts?

Comment: I suggest more caution when assuming it's the other person who has it wrong. Just because today you don't see that particular confusion in the USA does not mean that the confusion has always been impossible everywhere.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ I'm not sure what you mean. This isn't a matter of regional differences and the OP's conclusions are demonstrably wrong. Could you clarify?

Comment: @jimrings: I would like to see that demonstration, especially since it requires proving a negative - "no-one has ever made a 27", 28" or 29" tyre that fits a 700c rim". I am going to leave 26" out because it would be perilously close to rim tape. Sheldon claims that a 28 x 1 5/8 will fit a 622 rim, for example, making your claim that it doesn't seem risky.

Comment: My substantive point, however, is that you're better to focus on the "edited after accepting an answer" or "edit adds extraneous information" rather than "I think the edit is factually incorrect".

Comment: The OP's conclusion was that he could mount **any** 26, 27, etc tire on his 622 rim as long as he checked that the width is compatible. That's the assumption that is incorrect. I didn't claim that there's never been a tire labeled 26, 27, etc that will fit on a 622, although I'm guessing you'd be hard-pressed to find one that did. And I said *some* 28s will fit and some won't.

Comment: Fair point about distinguishing between "edited after accepting" "and edit adds extraneous information" though.

Comment: I read that as they could mount *some* 26,27,28,20 tyres, not just any of them. The whole question was premised on "some tyres don't fit, how does the label explain that". Different ways of reading the question are another reason that editing is fraught, BTW. Some SE sites have overenthusiastic editors who make it very difficult to ask certain questions.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ It seems like a stretch to me to read it like that, but I guess I can see it. But the point is well taken though that something that is "obviously" read one way to one person is just as obviously read another way to someone else. You should sum all of that up into an answer so people can vote on it.

Comment: I struggle to think of an answer that wouldn't just add to the confusion :)

Answer (score 3):

**If the edit changes the original question that has an accepted answer, then it should be rolled back.**

You might also consider suggesting that OP either ask another question (if it does change the original question) or continue discussion in a chatroom or comments. As long as you aren't combative, usually a comment like

> *That isn't really relevant to your question, but I'd enjoy discussing your conclusion more in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome)*

will suffice if you feel the need to explain why their conclusion is incorrect.

As for the question you linked to, I don't really think their added "*explanation*" changes the question. I would be more apt to remove it simply because it is irrelevant and needlessly bloats the question. You can always leave a detailed reason in the Edit Summary and if, for whatever reason, OP is bellicose and/or reverts the rollback you should just flag and leave it to the mods to decide.